# Can't remove completely an old file in Angular CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I googled alot but I couldn't find an answer and its been two hours already and I am getting really angry on this, please help me.

I created by mistake a service with uppercase and then I deleted it or renamed can't remember since the error popped when I restarted my PC, and it didn't complained yesterday, and I haven't touched today those files.

Here is the warning:

```
WARNING in ./src/app/_Services/hidden-VEHICLES.service.ts
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with     other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
*     E:\Vehicles\Vehicles\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\index.js!E:\Vehicles\Vehi    cles\src\app\_Services\hidden-VEHICLES.service.ts
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    E:\Vehicles\Vehicles\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\index.js!E:\Vehicles\Vehi    cles\src\app\bookmarked-vehicle\bookmarked-vehicle.component.ts
*     E:\Vehicles\Vehicles\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\index.js!E:\Vehicles\Vehi    cles\src\app\_Services\hidden-vehicles.service.ts
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
    E:\Vehicles\Vehicles\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\index.js!E:\Vehicles\Vehi    cles\src\app\app.module.ts
```

Here is the error:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/_Services/hidden-VEHICLES.service.ts
Module build failed: Error: E:\Vehicles\Vehicles\src\app\_Services\hidden-VEHICLES.service.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (E:\Vehicles\Vehicles\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:674:23)
at plugin.done.then (E:\Vehicles\Vehicles\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:467:39)
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

Current file name is not "hidden-VEHICLES.service.ts" it is hidden-vehicles.service.ts, if I go reveal folder it knows which file the one with uppercase.

I checked all files that are mentioned in the error and warning but since I am not an experienced with Angular and Typescript I can't see something wrong.

Since angular doesn't have destroy or remove to make sure everything is removed from everywhere I don't know where to find all references about the uppercase filename.

If I remove the service file I get:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/_Services/hidden-VEHICLES.service.ts
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
'E:\Vehicles\Vehicles\src\app\_Services\hidden-VEHICLES.service.ts'
ERROR in ./src/app/_Services/hidden-vehicles.service.ts
 Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
'E:\Vehicles\Vehicles\src\app\_Services\hidden-vehicles.service.ts'
```

Uppercase filename has to go but I can't find it anywhere defined or referenced.

EDIT: Alright after removing and adding back the file my app runs but I still have the warning.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have a github repository so that we can browse your files ? If not, could you post the deployed structure of your prject, with the code of this service ?

Comment: let me sync the files.

Comment: https://github.com/EduardRotaru/Vehicles/tree/master/src/app/_Services Just don't laugh too much about my app, its my first one and I am pretty trash :)

Comment: I wouldn't laugh, everybody has to start somewhere. I've found your issue, feel free to look at my answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into `src/app/bookmarked-vehicle/bookmarked-vehicle.component.ts`, you will find that :

```
import { HiddenItemsService } from '../_Services/hidden-VEHICLES.service';
```

I think this is your issue !

Comment: Thank you man a lot, I have no idea how I missed that spot, and visual studio code wasn't getting red either.

Comment: Well, github did point it out. I just searched for `hidden-vehicles`, and since the search is not case sensitive, it popped at the end of the results !

Comment: LOL I didn't knew this! nice trick to learn. I was really over thinking that Angular defines file names somewhere behind in some files and kept searching this lead since I haven't found in my files where the problem was in the first place. Thank you again :)